# Interacting with specific elements in an array; Processing 3

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, random, processing

I'm trying to create a grid of squares that "turn on" when the correct key is typed, then "turn off" when they are clicked with a mouse. In my program, a random index number is generated which corresponds to the Unicode value for particular key, and a random square on a grid is colored green when you press that key. Upon the re-coloring, a new index number in generated for a different key, and so on. A mouse click on the last colored square is able to "un-color” it (change to black), but not any other previously colored squares.

The problem seems to be that the mousePressed code is tied to whichever element in the array was last colored, but I can’t figure out how to make it interact with *any* of the elements in the array that have been colored. Is it even possible? I considered changing the array so that every element's position in the array itself is shuffled, but the shapes that it creates are still arranged in a grid, then iterating backwards with every mouse click. But I can’t seem to figure out how to shuffle an array without getting into java, which I'm not familiar with. Is this a solvable problem or should I somehow adjust my code? Here's what I have so far:

Primary script:

```
int cols = 16;
int rows = 10;
boolean light = false;

Box[][] boxes = new Box[cols][rows];

int keyIndex = int(random(97, 122));
int randI = (int)random(0, cols);
int randJ = (int)random(0, rows);

void setup() {
  size (800, 600);
  background (0);
  for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      boxes[i][j] = new Box(i, j);
    }
  }
  println(keyIndex);
}


void draw() { 
  if (light == true) {
    boxes[randI][randJ].rollover(mouseX, mouseY);
    boxes[randI][randJ].displayOn();
  } else {
    boxes[randI][randJ].displayOff();
  }
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (boxes[randI][randJ].onPress(mouseX, mouseY)) {
    println("yes");
    light = false;
  } else {
    println("no");
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (boxes[randI][randJ].keyRight()) {
    light = true;
    randI = (int)random(0, cols);
    randJ = (int)random(0, rows);
    keyIndex = int(random(97, 120));
    println(keyIndex);
  }
}
```

"Box" class:

```
class Box {

  float x, y;
  color c;
  int size = 50;

  Box (int valX, int valY) {
    x = valX * size;
    y = (int) random(0, valY) * size;
  }

  void displayOn() {
    fill(c);
    rect(x, y, size, size);
    c = #b1f64d;
  }

  void displayOff() {
    fill(c);
    rect(x, y, size, size);
    c = #000000;
  }

  void rollover(float mx, float my) {
    if (mx > x && mx < x + size && my > y && my < y + size) {
      c = 126;
    }
  }

  boolean onPress(float mx, float my) {
    if (mx > x && mx < x + size && my > y && my < y + size) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  boolean keyRight() {
    if (key == keyIndex) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of singe variable `boolean light = false;` you need a member variable of the class `Box`:

`boolean light = false;`

```java
class Box {

    boolean light = false;
    float x, y;
    color c;
    int size = 50;

    Box (int valX, int valY) {
        x = valX * size;
        y = valY * size;
    }

    .....
}
```

Now each box object can hold the information, whether it is "lighted" or not.

In the `draw` function you have to draw all the boxes, each dependent on its state
`boxes[i][j].light` use 2 nested `for` loops for this:

```java
void draw() { 

    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

            if (boxes[i][j].light == true) {
                 boxes[i][j].rollover(mouseX, mouseY);
                 boxes[i][j].displayOn();
            } else {
                 boxes[i][j].displayOff();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `mousePressed` you have to check all `Box` objects with state `boxes[i][j].light`, whether `mouseX` and `mouseY` is on:

```java
void mousePressed() {
    boolean hit = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {

        if (boxes[i][j].light == true && boxes[i][j].onPress(mouseX, mouseY)) {
            boxes[i][j].light = false;
            hit = true;
        }
      }
    }
    println(hit ? "yes" : "no");
}
```

Finally you have to set the member `boxes[randI][randJ].light` in the function `keyPressed`, instead of the variable `light`, which doesn't exist any more:

```java
void keyPressed() {
    if (boxes[randI][randJ].keyRight()) {
        boxes[randI][randJ].light = true;
        randI = (int)random(0, cols);
        randJ = (int)random(0, rows);
        keyIndex = int(random(97, 120));
        println(keyIndex, char(keyIndex));
    }
}
```

Comment: Holy smokes, I didn't know that you could use the dot to access data, I thought it was only for methods. That makes an enormous difference. Thank you so much, this was very well-explained. I am wondering why you have to use nested loops for every function? I.e. why does Processing require (what I understand is) the re-creation of an array for each function? Or is that not what's happening?

Comment: @hawkjones The nested loops are required to traverse all the boxes in the 2 dimensional array. Note you have to check the the `.light` state of each box and you have to ask each box with where `.light == true` if the mouse is on.